# Check if there are any subscribers to an event handler whilst using a custom delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates

So the idea was simple, how do i check if there are any duplicate subscribers.

So essentially if I have

> _moduleEvent += _coachesEvents.OnDifficultyScoreListChanged;

subscribed in multiple
locations, I don't want the method called twice (or more).

My Current code (with added logic after researching):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Delegate that points to the multiple module methods
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        private delegate void ModuleEventHandler(object sender, OpportunityEventArgs args);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private event ModuleEventHandler _moduleEvent
        {
            add
            {
                if (_moduleEvent == null || !_moduleEvent.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
                {
                    _moduleEvent += value;
                }
            }
            remove
            {
                _moduleEvent -= value;
            }
        }
```

In the event where I am checking if it's null and checking the GetInnvocationList, I get an error that _moduleEvent should appear on the left hand side of += etc.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Check whether there are any subscribers
        /// </summary>
        private void _onModuleEvent(BusinessEntities.Opportunity o)
        {
            if (_moduleEvent != null)
                _moduleEvent(this, new OpportunityEventArgs() { Opportunity = o });
        }
```

I also see the _moduleEvent should appear on the left hand side of += error above.

I can only assume it's do with the custom delegate ? If I remove the add/remove in the eventHandler obviously all works fine.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, I've been programming this whole time without knowing about it. More on topic, OP, couldn't you just unconditionally try removing the handler before adding it?

Comment: @Asad actually, [custom event accessors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713648.aspx) were added in 2008. They are very rarely used for edge cases, eg inheriting from two interfaces with the same event name

Comment: I could do, but without going into to much detail about the system. It's going to be rather large and event heavy. So essentially there will be system events and module events. Ideally was looking for a clean robust way of doing this.

Comment: I've done some more research on events, and there seems to be a problem with your code. You need to having a private "backing" event (kind of like backing fields) that is defined like so `private event ModuleEventHandler _moduleEvent;`, period. Then you can add a `public event` that provides *accessors* to this private event, but *cannot be raised itself*. E.g. you can do `public event ModuleEventHandler ModuleEvent { add { _moduleEvent += value; } remove { _moduleEvent -= value; } }`. You can raise and null check `_moduleEvent`, but you can't do either of those things for `ModuleEvent`.

Comment: @TezWingfield Check out the code here: http://ideone.com/7wnxL3. It think that does what you want it to do.

Comment: @Asad...You should mock that link up as the answer. I didn't even know that backing field existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should create dictionary and do check for that

Create class as below

```
public class Subscription
{
  public readonly MethodInfo MethodInfo;
  public readonly WeakReference TargetObjet;

  public Subscription(Action<Tmessage> action, EventAggregator eventAggregator)
  {
      MethodInfo = action.Method;
      TargetObjet = new WeakReference(action.Target);
  }
}
```

than use this class in your class where expose event

```
Public class EventExposer
{
  private Dictionary<Type, IList> subscriber;

  public EventExposer()
  {
            subscriber = new Dictionary<Type, IList>();
  }

   public void AddEvent(Action action)
   {
            Type t = typeof(action.Target);
            if (!subscriber.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                    subscriber.Add(t, action);
            }
   }

}
```